# No route matches [POST] error Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to trigger a method via button but I have a little rounting issue.

Here is my view code :

```
   <% @orders.each do |order| %>
     <% if order.confirm == true %>
     <tr class="confirmed">
       <% else %>
     <tr class="not_confirmed">
     <% end %> 
       <td><%= order.name %></td>
       <td><%= order.address %></td>
       <td><%= order.email %></td>
       <td><%= order.pay_type %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Show', order %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
       <td><%= button_to "Confirm payment", :controller => :orders, :action => :confirm  %></td>
```

Here is method definition from controller :

```
def confirm
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.confirm = true
end
```

And here from routes.rb:

```
resources :orders do
    put :confirm, :on => :collection
end
```

When i press button i got **No route matches [POST] "/orders/confirm"** error

In addition i paste screen from rake:routes

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch [http verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) There is a difference between POST and PUT request.
In your routes, you define PUT route. And your request is POST - that's why it does not work.

If you want to stay with PUT, try this:

```
<%= button_to "Confirm payment", :controller => :orders, :action => :confirm, :method => :put  %>
```